Why is my kotlin code involving generics not compiling?
Can anyone help me figure out why this doesn't compile, and if possible help me find a way to get it to:
fun <KEY,VALUE> Map<KEY,List<VALUE>>.inverse(): Map<VALUE, List<KEY>> {
  val map = mutableMapOf<VALUE, List<KEY>>()
  this.forEach { (key, listOfValues) ->
    listOfValues.forEach { value ->
      map[value] = map[value]?.plus(key) ?: listOf(key)
    }
  }
  return map
}

fun <KEY,VALUE> Map<KEY,VALUE>.inverse(): Map<VALUE, List<KEY>> {
  val map = mutableMapOf<VALUE, List<KEY>>()
  this.forEach { (key, value) ->
    map[value] = map[value]?.plus(key) ?: listOf(key)
  }
  return map
}

The error message I am getting is
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (inverse(Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map;):
    fun <KEY, VALUE> Map<KEY, VALUE>.inverse(): Map<VALUE, List<KEY>> defined in <package>
    fun <KEY, VALUE> Map<KEY, List<VALUE>>.inverse(): Map<VALUE, List<KEY>> defined in <package>


The error message is actually pretty clear. Both functions have the same name, receive the same parameters (Map) and return the same type (Map). Type parameters of both maps don't matter because of type erasure, so from the perspective of the JVM these functions are identical and can't coexist.
You need to rename one of them to distinguish them. You can either rename the Kotlin function or, if you like to keep the same name in Kotlin and you target JVM, you can rename them only in the JVM:
@JvmName("multimapInverse")
fun <KEY,VALUE> Map<KEY,List<VALUE>>.inverse(): Map<VALUE, List<KEY>> { ... }

@JvmName("mapInverse")
fun <KEY,VALUE> Map<KEY,VALUE>.inverse(): Map<VALUE, List<KEY>> { ... }

